# Does Ajax still gets a json even though not setting a method get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I was just wondering how ajax requests behaves, because I just accidentally commented out my method:"get" in my ajax request but it still gets the json file though... I'm using handlebars because I'm just learning it.

My Html

```
<div class="page-wrap">
      <h1>Handlebars Tutorial</h1>
    <div id="pets-container">
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
        {{#each pets}}
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        {{/each}}

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</div>
```

My script:

```
 $(function(){
        $.myreq = $.ajax({
           url:'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/pets-data.json',
           //method: 'GET',
           dataType: 'json'
        });//ajax 
        $.myreq.done(appendData);
        function appendData(data){
            console.log(data);
            var source   = $("#template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var petsContainers = $('#pets-container').html(template(data));
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's just defaulting to the `get` method. Nothing crazy going on :)

Comment: The `method` relates to how data is passed in the *request*, whereas the `dataType` is the expected format of the *response*. They're unrelated, and in your case (even aside from `'get'` being the default when not specified) you're not actually including any data in the request anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **method (default: 'GET')**
>
> Type: String The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST",
>   "GET", "PUT"). (version added: 1.9.0)

Default `method` when not specified is `GET`.